bibtex: citing author name in numbered-citation style
My LaTeX document uses natbib and was originally written for author-date citation styles. Now my publisher forces me to convert to their numbered-citation style:
Original: . . . blah blah was found (Johnson 2014).
Fixed: . . . blah blah was found [19].

The above conversion is easy: You just redefine the \citep command of natbib. But the following is tough:
Original: Johnson's (2014) method is . . .
Fixed: Johnson's [19] method is . . .

because the publisher's .bst style omits the author information from the \bibitem entries it generates.
The publisher is PLOS and they say they use the "Vancouver" style. So I tried both vancouver.bst and vancouver-authoryear.bst but the former still omits the author information and the latter just does everything in the traditional author-year way.
So, is there a Vancouver-like style that retains the author-year information in the \bibitem entries?
If not, perhaps I'd have to write a script that transplants the author-year information from a author-year-style bbl to the number-style bbl which the publisher's .bst generates.
[By the way, my original article uses biblatex. I was surprised that even a new-ish publisher like PLOS still uses bibtex. All publishers seem to be stuck at 2000.]
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
  title = {Handbook of mathematical functions},
  author = {Abramowitz, Milton and Stegun, Irene A.},
  year = {1965},
  pages = {1060},
  publisher = {Dover},
  location = {New York}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\cite{book1}\\     % fine
\citep{book1}\\    % fine
\citet{book1}\\    % Author not available!
\citeauthor{book1} % Author not available!
%\citeyear{book1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
\end{document}


The natbib package provides the macros \citeauthor and citeyear, which work just fine even if natbib is loaded with the option numbers to produce numeric-style citation call-outs by default. Incidentally, why are you using plain instead of plainnat?

@Mico Thanks, but I don't know if you ran my sample code? The \citeauthor command does not work fine, because the \bibitem entry doesn't include the author information. I use plain just to illustrate my problem.  The style I actually use is called plos2015.bst, but plain.bst reproduces the same problem for the same reason.

Well, if the plos2015 bib style is no more capable than the plain style, then \citeauthor and \citeyear can't work. So sorry to have wasted your time.

@Mico No apologies are called for. My motivation was to see if somebody knows "some tricks", like modifying an existing numbered-citation-style bst file to include the author information in the bbl file.  (I tried replacing a function in the problematic style file with a corresponding function in an author-date-style bst, which unfortunately resulted in an error which I didn't understand.)
